# Implementing functions in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, function, swift, ios8

I am new to swift and trying to implement a simple function that takes minimum and max number as input and returns an array with all the numbers in the limit. I am getting an error 
//Error: Reference to generic type 'Array' requires arguments in <...>
may I know what I am missing on?

```
func serialNumberLimits(minimumNumber n1:Int, maximumNumber n2:Int) -> Array {

// Initialized an empty array
var array = Int[]()

//Initialized a "Temp" variable
var temp:Int = 0


for index in n1..n2 {

    temp += n1
    n1++

    if index == 1 { array.insert(temp, atIndex: 0) }

    else { array.insert(temp, atIndex: index-1) }

}

return array

}
```

Comment: Note that `[Int](n1 ... n2)` gives you an integer array with given range (using the "new" array syntax from Beta 3).

Answer (score 5):

Use following function
1)As you are using `n1` in function and changing its value so declare it as `var` as all parameters are `constants` in swift by default

2)Use `Array<Int>` as it needs to be define which type of array is in swift.Swift is strongly typed language so all type need to be defined.

Run following code it will compile with no errors

```
func serialNumberLimits(var minimumNumber n1:Int, maximumNumber n2:Int) -> Array<Int> {

    // Initialized an empty array
    var array = Int[]()

    //Initialized a "Temp" variable
    var temp:Int = 0


    for index in n1..n2 {

        temp += n1
        n1++

        if index == 1 { array.insert(temp, atIndex: 0) }

        else { array.insert(temp, atIndex: index) }

    }

    return array

}
```

Comment: This won't compile on the newest beta. The exclusive range operator has been replaced by `..<` and the array convenience syntax has been changed to `[Int]`.

Comment: Yes it is of `beta 2` code as posted in `question`.I have compiled on `Beta 3` and change for `beta 2`

Comment: @Revanth get new xcode as many things changes in beta 3 and 4 like array define `var array = [Int]()`, `n1..<n2` changed