# swift function returning an Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Im learning Swift and I can understand how to create a simple function that takes in an Array and returns an Array. Heres my code:

```
 func myArrayFunc(inputArray:Array) -> Array{

 var newArray = inputArray

// do stuff with newArray

 return newArray
 }
```

The red error I get is: Reference to generic type 'Array" requires arguments in <>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing functions in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897267/implementing-functions-in-swift)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Swift `Array` is generic type, so you have to specify what type array contains. For example:

```
func myArrayFunc(inputArray:Array<Int>) -> Array<Int> {}
```

If you want your function to be generic then use:

```
func myArrayFunc<T>(inputArray:Array<T>) -> Array<T> {}
```

If you don't want to specify type or have generic function use `Any` type:

```
func myArrayFunc(inputArray:Array<Any>) -> Array<Any> {}
```

Comment: Please let me know how to call a return type function which returns an array having dictionaries inside it.

Answer (score 8):

Depends on what is it exactly you want to do. If you want a specialized function that takes an array of a specific type MyType, then you could write something like:

```
func myArrayFunc(inputArray: [MyType]) -> [MyType] {
    // do something to inputArray, perhaps copy it?
}
```

If you want a generic array function, then you have to use generics. This would take an array of generic type T and return an array of generic type U:

```
func myGenericArrayFunc<T, U>(inputArray: [T]) -> [U] {

}
```

Comment: Please let me know how to call a return type function which returns an array having dictionaries inside it.

Answer (score 1):

thanks all (especially Kirsteins). So I've come up with this example that works well and looks logical:

```
func myArrayFunc(inputArray:Array<String>) -> Array<String>{

var newArray = inputArray

// do stuff with newArray

return newArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an `Array` in Swift, but there are arrays of a certain type, so you should give the function a generic type, like in:

```
func myArrayFunc<T>(inputArray:Array<T>) -> Array<T>{  
   // do what you want with the array
}
```

and then call it by instantiating T to a specific type, and passing an array of such type.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
func myArrayFunc<T>(inputArray:Array<T>) -> Array<T> {

  var newArray = inputArray

  // do stuff with newArray

  return newArray
}
```

You declare the generic type `T`, which is just a placeholder. Because it has no requirements `T` can be replaced by any type (when the function is called). So your function could be called like this:

```
myArrayFunc([1, 2, 3])
```

or this:

```
myArrayFunc(["a", "b", "c"])
```

The preferred syntax is generally `[T]` rather than `Array<T>`, though. (although both are correct)

```
func myArrayFunc<T>(inputArray: [T]) -> [T] {

  var newArray = inputArray

  // do stuff with newArray

  return newArray
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var test = doArray([true,true,true])

test.count
func doArray(arr : [AnyObject]) -> [AnyObject] {

   var _arr = arr

return _arr
}
```

Comment: `AnyObject` is a type, not a generic. So your function would only accept arrays of `AnyObject`. Your code does not run.

Comment: Hmm... [It didn't run for me...](http://imgur.com/kW5w3po). I think there's some implicit conversion going on. Check out [this swiftstub](http://swiftstub.com/799141797/?v=beta)

Comment: Also, `[1, 1, 1]` is not the same as `[true, true, true]`

Comment: [1,1,1] is the same as [true,true, true], false would be [0,0,0] I assume that's coming from the Bool conversion to AnyObject. Anyway there is accepted answer answer with generics.